# what is difference between login.jsp and login.jsp?success=1

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am using the following code for login I want to what is the difference between redirecting to `main.jsp` and `main.jsp?success=1`

```
if(flag==1){
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
            session.setAttribute("ukey",uname );
            System.out.println("------------------------------\n"+session.getAttribute("ukey")+" logged in!!!\n------------------------------");
            response.sendRedirect("main.jsp?success=1");
        }

        else
        {
            //HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            System.out.println("------------------------------\nEmail or Password is wrong!!!!!!!!\n------------------------------");   
            response.sendRedirect("login.jsp?error=1");
            //session.setAttribute("error",invalid);
        }`if(flag==1){
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
            session.setAttribute("ukey",uname );
            System.out.println("------------------------------\n"+session.getAttribute("ukey")+" logged in!!!\n------------------------------");
            response.sendRedirect("main.jsp?success=1");
        }

        else
        {
            //HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            System.out.println("------------------------------\nEmail or Password is wrong!!!!!!!!\n------------------------------");   
            response.sendRedirect("login.jsp?error=1");
            //session.setAttribute("error",invalid);
        }`
```

Comment: If you redirect to main.jsp then the browser goes to main.jsp. If you redirect to main.jsp?success=1 then the browser goes to main.jsp?success=1. (Or have I misunderstood your question?)

Answer (score 1):

> > what is the differnece between redirecting to main.jsp and main.jsp?success=1

With `main.jsp?success=1` you are passing request parameter called success to main.jsp and with `main.jsp` you aren't passing any request parameters to main.jsp.